# Does anyone know which printer language is this?

Tags: printing, postscript, zpl, printer-control-language, epl

```
comment("Ply CUSTOMER COPY")
include("tables/default.txt")
formtype("ABC*1*STORE-A", )
include("fields/item_ar1.txt")
ply("ABC*1*STORE-A#CUSTOMER COPY", , 0, 11, 0, "condition_each order=0 ")
if(FORM_TYPE="D")
  include("d_form/ABC_1")
else()
  papersize("letter")
  orientation("portrait")
  duplex("no")
  papersource("tray3")
  paperbin("standard")
  include("maps/item_ar1_map.txt")
  if(print_overlays())
    include("s_form/8738232\900_")
    adjust(0.000, 0.000)
    move(0.625, 0.250)
    color(0, 0, 0)
    typeface("courier")
    size(12.000)
    style("regular")
    weight("medium")
    symbolset("Roman-8")
    text("__________")
  endif()
endif()
```

Comment: It looks like a macro language (`else()`), possibly custom made for a specific company or installation.

Comment: Thanks @luserdroog